# A number theoretical problem

Tags: number-theory

How many pairs $(A,B)$ are there up to $n$ such that $\gcd(A,B)=B$ and $B^2\neq A$? If we consider $n=5$, we have $25$ possible pairs, $(1,1)$, $(1,2)$, $(1,3)$, $(1,4)$, $(1,5)$, $(2,1)$, $(2,2)$, $(2,3)$, $(2,4)$, $(2,5)$, $\dots$, $(5,5)$.

Eight of these satisfy the above condition. My main objective is to find out the number
of such pairs if $n$ is given, with a efficient method.

So far I know I have to count those pairs $(A,B)$ where $A$ is divisible by $B$. Hence if I find out the number of divisors of all the numbers up to $N$, we will have the number of pair $\gcd(A,B)=B$.

For example,for $n=10$, $1$ has one divisor, $2$ has two divisors, ..., and $10$ has four divisors. So the total number of "candidate" pairs is $1+2+2+3+2+4+2+4+3+4=27$. We now remove the pairs with $B^2=A$, of which there are three, so our desired result is $24$.

One of my friends showed me  a method but he didn't state the reasoning behind it.

Here, I'm presenting his method for $n=10$.

$$\begin{align*}
    2\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor} \big(\lfloor n/i\rfloor-i\big)
    &=2\big(\lfloor 10/1\rfloor - 1 + \lfloor10/2\rfloor - 2 + \lfloor10/3\rfloor - 3\big)\\
    &= 2\big(10 - 1 + 5 - 2 + 3 - 3\big) \\
    &= 24\,.
\end{align*}$$

Why does this give the right answer?

Can anyone clearly explain the reasoning behind the above method in detail?

Comment: I edited your question to remove the sub-questions since explaining why the formula gives the right answer necessarily involves explaining all parts of the formula -- you can't explain why the formula works without explaining why $-i$ appears in the sum, for example.

Comment: This is a pure mathematics question without any obvious relation to CS (despite being part of a foundational mathematics curriculum for CS students). Hence, it belongs on [math.SE]; I'm migrating it now.